# Can we elicit slot of a different intent in Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

If our backend receive a request for say `AMAZON.YesIntent` or any other custom intent. Can we Elicit slot of a different intent than the triggered intent as response.

Ex:

```
...
user: Yes
     (Amazon.YesIntent is mapped)
Alexa: Which city do you want to stay in?
     (elicit slot of another intent)
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes this is now possible, read the update section

<strike>Unfortunately you can't. Only updated intent of same type can be sent with a `Dialog.ElicitSlot` directive.</strike>

> Note that you cannot change intents when returning a Dialog directive,
>   so the intent name and set of slots must match the intent sent to your
>   skill.

You will receive an "Invalid Directive" card and *"There was some problem with the requested skills response"* as error message.

### Update (April, 8th 2019)

Use `updateIntent` object to specify the new intent whose slot has to be triggered. When you update the Intent object originally sent to your skill with the new `updateIntent`, **include all of the slots**, including any empty slots you are not changing.

```
{
  "type": "Dialog.ElicitSlot",
  "slotToElicit": "slotOfSomeOtherIntent",
  "updatedIntent": {
    "name": "SomeOtherIntent",
    "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
    "slots": {
      "slotOfSomeOtherIntent": {
        "name": "slotOfSomeOtherIntent",
        "value": "string",
        "resolutions": {},
        "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Read more about [Change the intent or update slot values during the dialog](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html#use-updatedintent)
Read more about [ElicitSlot Directive](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html#elicitslot)

Comment: Is this still true? The docs you link to make it sound possible to pass the other intent in updatedIntent even under ElicitSlot Directive: "Use this to change intents during the dialog or set slot values and confirmation status."

Comment: At the time of writing it was not possible. Now it's possible using updatedIntent. I will update my answer shortly. Thank you for pointing it out.